# Is it possble to insert a python function into SQL query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a case statement in SQL that says if 2 parameters past then do this if 3 then that...

I tried to use len(xyz) I know why my code is wrong but I am not sure how to achieve this... else I'll have to write less compact code with if statements on the outside

```
LocAll = ('RSA','EC','Grahamstown')

 """SELECT * 
    FROM User_Skills US, User_Profile UP 
    WHERE US.UserId = UP.UserId

    CASE WHEN len{0} = {1} THEN 
    UP.country = {2} 
    AND UP.state= {3} 
    AND UP.city= {4}


    """.format(LocAll, 3,LocAll[0],LocAll[1],LocAll[2]) )
```

Thank you

As suggested in the comments I used {0} and placed the function in the .format as (len(LocAll)....)

```
 """SELECT *, 

        CASE WHEN {0} = {1} 
        THEN 

            WHERE 
            US.UserId = UP.UserId AND
            UP.country = {2} 
            AND UP.state= {3} 
            AND UP.city= {4} 
        END 

        FROM User_Skills US, User_Profile UP       

    """.format(len(LocAll), 3,LocAll[0],LocAll[1],LocAll[2]) )
```

However I get an syntax error?

Comment: Instead of LocAll use, len(LocAll ) and instead len{0} use {0}

Comment: And what is the syntax error?

Comment: Error  syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Comment: I changed the query to :SELECT *, 
                SELECT *, 
                
         CASE WHEN {0} = {1} THEN 

    WHERE US.UserId = UP.UserId AND
    UP.country = {2} 
    AND UP.state= {3} 
    AND UP.city= {4} END FROM User_Skills US, User_Profile UP

Comment: What are you trying to do with your case statement ?  your SQL is quite broken, so it's hard to guess what you're attempting to do, so try to describe it.

Comment: I am trying to say that if the location variable LocAll only has country and state then use a different case... the reason i did it this way is because if only country and state are past and not city then I dont get the return value I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print out and examine the string resulting from the substitution: You get things like

```
           UP.country = RSA
```

See it? Since `RSA` is a string, you need to add quotes around it:

```
           UP.country = '{}'
```

But it would be far better to use "prepared statements" and let your database module do the substitution for you-- otherwise your code will crash again the first time you search for a string containing a single quote. Maybe you did intend to use a prepared statement? Your code is just using python's regular string substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `WHERE` expression to the valid `CASE` syntax:

```
LocAll = ('RSA','EC','Grahamstown')

 """SELECT
        * 
    FROM 
        User_Skills US, User_Profile UP 
    WHERE 
        US.UserId = UP.UserId
        AND
        1 = CASE WHEN 
                {0} = {1} 
                AND UP.country = {2} 
                AND UP.state= {3} 
                AND UP.city= {4}
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

""".format(len(LocAll), 3, LocAll[0], LocAll[1], LocAll[2]) )
```